# Unable to get my astable multi-vibrator working in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, oscillator, square, astable, falstad

I'm trying to build a basic square wave oscillator using an astable vibrator made with an op-amp for my *Intro to Circuits* class.

Unfortunately, I cannot get LTspice to simulate the oscillations.

I've tried a good chunk of the op-amps available. I've also tried varying resistor values, VCC and VEE, capacitance, transient settings, and the initial voltage on the capacitor. I can get this to somewhat simulate on Farstad, but how do I get it to simulate on LTspice?

Edit- I am aware that voltages attached to VCC and VEE have incorrect polarity, it still doesn't work if they are correct.

Edit2- The capacitance in 100 nF, voltage is read from the output of op-amp. Zooming in on the photo should help if you have difficulty reading some of the values.

Edit3- This is the latest version of LTspice running on a Windows 11 machine.

[image]

Comment: There are problems with Astables on the bench and on the sim .Old people have seen this but they cannot read your photo so cant answer your question.

Comment: The images don’t show up well, small and bad color scheme.

Comment: Also Win 7 isn't supported anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one problem: The output of the op-amp is connected to GND.

There may be other problems.

[image]

Comment: Taking the output off ground and changing my positive input resistors to lower values seemed to have fixed it, thank you.